# mpirun 2 processes on a Intel Core 2 Duo but only 1 process shows up

Tags: c++, macos, mpi

I am running a test mpi program in mac os x 10.6.8. The processor is Intel Core 2 Duo. The program is from [boost mpi documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html):

```
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    boost::mpi::environment env(argc, argv);
    boost::mpi::communicator w;
    std::cout << "process " << w.rank() << " of " << w.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it and ran it with:

```
mpirun -np 2 a.out
```

But got the following result:

```
process 0 of 1
process 0 of 1
```

which, I think, means there was only one process running. What did I do wrong? I think I can create 2 processes on a Intel Duo?

Thanks,

Gary

Comment: What flavour of MPI are you using, and are you sure that boost::mpi has been built with the same library?

Comment: Openmpi. Thanks, you asked the right question. I just did 
otool -L libboost_mpi.dylib and find that it is linking to the openmpi in /usr/lib that comes with mac, instead of the one I newly compiled in /opt/openmpi-1.4.5/lib. 

How can I direct boost to build mpi with the new openmpi library sitting in a directory other than the default /usr/lib?

Comment: I have never had problems with it by following [these build instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/mpi/getting_started.html#mpi.config).

Comment: You can create processes as many as you want on intel Duo but only creating 2 processes in intel Duo is efficient because your cpu can do only 2 works at each time so other processes that you made must wait for each other to complete their works.

Comment: The OPs problem, and the remark by talonmies, are general to MPI and not specific to boost::mpi. The same behavior results e.g. if code is compiled with `mpic++.mpich2`, and run with `mpirun.openmpi`.